# get string from multi level json in php

Tags: php, json

i am trying to get few strings from json but with no success  yet :(

i tried many codes but still no luck and can't understand this fully

the json example is :

```
{
    "nginx_version": "1.7.11.3 Gryphon",
    "nginx_rtmp_version": "1.1.4",
    "built": "Mar 19 2015 20:36:41",
    "pid": "4680",
    "uptime": "1876",
    "naccepted": "3",
    "bw_in": "404904",
    "bytes_in": "83699680",
    "bw_out": "404912",
    "bytes_out": "83700478",
    "server": {
        "application": [{
            "name": "msdk",
            "live": {
                "stream": {
                    "name": "xkiz531",
                    "time": "1854519",
                    "bw_in": "399752",
                    "bytes_in": "82628640",
                    "bw_out": "399752",
                    "bytes_out": "82628588",
                    "bw_audio": "178480",
                    "bw_video": "221272",
                    "client": [{
                        "id": "2788",
                        "address": "example.com\/live\/live",
                        "time": "1854519",
                        "flashver": "ngx-local-relay",
                        "dropped": "0",
                        "avsync": "-14",
                        "timestamp": "1853566",
                        "active": []
                    }, {
                        "id": "2787",
                        "address": "197.14.103.17",
                        "time": "1854987",
                        "flashver": "FMLE\/3.0 (compatible; FMSc\/1.0)",
                        "swfurl": "rtmp:\/\/example.com\/msdk",
                        "dropped": "0",
                        "avsync": "-14",
                        "timestamp": "1853566",
                        "publishing": [],
                        "active": []
                    }],
                    "meta": {
                        "video": {
                            "width": "1280",
                            "height": "720",
                            "frame_rate": "30",
                            "codec": "H264",
                            "profile": "High",
                            "compat": "0",
                            "level": "3.1"
                        },
                        "audio": {
                            "codec": "AAC",
                            "profile": "LC",
                            "channels": "2",
                            "sample_rate": "44100"
                        }
                    },
                    "nclients": "2",
                    "publishing": [],
                    "active": []
                },
                "nclients": "2"
            }
        }, {
            "name": "test",
            "live": {
                "nclients": "0"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

the code i have now is :

```
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);

var_dump($array);
foreach($array['items'] as $item) {
    echo $item['server']['application']['live']['stream']['name'];
}
```

i want to obtain the values of these keys on strings :

bw_audio, bw_video, width, height, frame_rate, codec, profile, audio codec & sample rate

Comment: I don't see `items` in the JSON.

Comment: `application` is an array. You need to use `['application'][0]` or iterate over it.

Comment: You want to get the keys `bw_audio`, `bw_video`, or you want to get the values of those keys?

Comment: the values of the keys .......... i am sorry i will update my question

Comment: I still don't see where `$array['items']` is. I assume the JSON you showed is `$array`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no `items` key in the JSON and `application` is an array so you should do:

```
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
echo $array['server']['application'][0]['live']['stream']['name'];
```

Note: if there may be more than one application, iterate `foreach` over the array instead of using `[0]`.

Comment: @chedlywalid You have no ```items``` key in the JSON. I edited my answer.